# awless installation with brew fails with invalid syntax errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to install awless using the following command:

```
brew tap wallix/awless; brew install awless
```

but I am getting invalid syntax errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to download and install awless using the following commands

`curl -sS https://webinstall.dev/awless | bash`

`export PATH="/Users/akshaybhadange/.local/bin:$PATH"`

Now awless is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [awless](https://github.com/wallix/awless) has not been maintained for a couple of years and should be considered deprecated. Please check this issue: https://github.com/wallix/awless/issues/297

Similar [brew installation issues](https://github.com/wallix/awless/issues/288) are reported in the project's issue tracker, but I don't think there are no efforts to get this fixed.